# Ember Simple Auth invalidate session with cookie store when 'NOT' remembered?

Tags: ember-simple-auth

I added a "remember me" function to my login component and followed the advice of the [authors](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#session-stores) on setting up the Cookie Store.

What I found, however, is when I set Cookie expiration to null and close the browser window without Logging Out, the session data is gone (Correct Behavior) BUT the session appears 'Authenticated' (Incorrect behavior).

Am I missing some way to automatically logout user?

Comment: Are you actually using the cookie session store?

Comment: Yes.  I have extended 'ember-simple-auth/session-stores/cookie' class, giving a custom cookie name, and I can see it showing up correctly in the Ember Inspector under "Container" -> "Session Store" -> "Application" object.